# Scramble/unscramble an integer value to/from hexadecimal string

Tags: go, cryptography, integer, hex

I'm attempting to implement some Go code to solve a problem in which I need to sufficiently obfuscate a known integer value by converting it into a seemingly random hexadecimal string, when provided a known key value as an additional input parameter. The resulting hexadecimal string needs to always be the same number of characters in length (ideally, <= 32 characters).

Furthermore, using the same key string value, I need to un-obfuscate the hexadecimal string back into the original integer. For additional context, I'd like to satisfy the following function signatures (but am open to alternative methods, if necessary):

```golang
func Scramble(key string, value int32) string {
  // TODO: Given a known key and value, generate a sufficiently unpredictable hexadecimal string.
}

func Unscramble(key string, value string) int32 {
  // TODO: Given a known key and value, generate the integer that created the hexadecimal string.
}

func main() {
  key := "Something super secret!"

  scrambled := Scramble(key, 135)
  fmt.Printf("Scrambled: %s\n", scrambled) // Scrambled: a1dec128b590b9ec3281110d6d188c26

  unscrambled := Unscramble(key, scrambled)
  fmt.Printf("Unscrambled: %d\n", unscrambled) // Unscrambled: 135
}
```

I *think* XOR'ing may be the right direction, but I'm unsure and not particularly familiar with the topic yet.

Any insight/direction would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if I can provide any additional context/clarifications.

Comment: XOR'ing twice or more with the same key means that a lot of information is quickly lost, read up about many-time pad. Using a block cipher is much more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many native or external packages to achieve what you want, but if you want to implement this yourself for a learning experience, you can try the following tack:

Rather than shuffle your data back and forth between string and int32 format - keep the data in its raw type and use Stringer methods to convert to hex - and helper methods/functions to convert to the desired type. This simplifies the scrambling/unscrambling logic - as the input types are the same for both.

```
// Code custom type so we can add stringer methods
type Code uint32

// String converts code to hex string format
func (c Code) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", uint32(c))
}

// CodeFromString gets a code from a hex string
func CodeFromString(hexs string) (Code, error) {
    ui, err := strconv.ParseUint(hexs, 16, 32)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    return Code(ui), nil
}

// XOR scrambles/unscrambles
func XOR(key, value Code) Code {
    return key ^ value
}
```

And to use:

```
keyHex := "74490a85"
valueHex := "d195c729"

value, _ := CodeFromString(valueHex)
key, _ := CodeFromString(keyHex)

scrambled := XOR(key, value)

unscrambled := XOR(key, scrambled)
```

Playground Example: https://play.golang.org/p/y5pbac_f8Z1